# How to do list with glyphicons and columns separated by vertical line in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to do list with some data and glyphicons sepearated by vertical line.
This is what I made already:

HTML:

```
<div class="containers vertical-divider">
  <div class="column one-third">
    <h1 class="span glyphicon glyphicon-th"></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="column two-thirds">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet vestib.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column two-thirds">
    <h3>Details</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column one-third">
    <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="column one-third">
    <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

CSS:

```
.vertical-divider{
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}

.vertical-divider:after {
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.vertical-divider .column:not(:first-child):after, .vertical-divider .columns:not(:first-child):after{
    background: #DDDDDD;
    bottom: 0;
    content: " ";
    margin-left: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
}

/* Very simple grid for example */
.containers { position: relative; width: 960px; margin: 20px auto; padding: 0; }

.containers .column, .containers .columns { float: left; display: inline; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; }

.containers .one-third.column { width: 50px; }

.containers .two-thirds.column { width: 250px; }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xxpe6fnw/

As you can see the problem is with glyphicons on the right side, also width in each column is not responsive.

If someone have better, easier idea to get similar result (maybe using some bootstrap features?), then I'm listening.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with input-group and input-group-addon.

I forked your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o7es6jvu/

```
<span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></h1></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But it's too ugly, and width is still not responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a new version of your code using `col-md-*` and `col-sm-*` responsive classes of Bootstrap.

Can you try this?

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row"><!-- Repeat this row for each line you want -->
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet vestib.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <h3>Details</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
        <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></h1>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End repeat -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle : [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/k6gyjvpa/)

Comment: What about vertical line?

Comment: Oops, forgot it! Coming soon :)

Comment: @Mistalis There's no need to declare col-md-* in the above. There is no change from the col-sm-* values. From the Bootstrap site: _Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any .col-md-* class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a .col-lg-* class is not present._

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**Markup**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <h1 class="span glyphicon glyphicon-th"></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet vestib.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Details</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <h1 class="span glyphicon glyphicon-th"></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet vestib.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Details</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <h1 class="span glyphicon glyphicon-th"></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Title</h3>
                        <p>consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet vestib.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Details</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <h1 class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
[class*="col-"]{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
.wrapper {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
}
.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 650px;
}
.container > .row{
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container > .row > div{
    border-right: 1px solid #f00;
}
.container > .row > div:last-child{
    border-right: none;
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/codeandcloud/d5b0ztxm/7/show/

Comment: At the moment is the best answer. By the way is it possible to add vertical line between columns - or is too complicated?

Answer (score 0):

Add this following code to align your vertical line, adjust margin and padding according to your plans. And to make it responsive on mobile device then for that you have to work using media query.

```
.vertical-divider{
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}

.vertical-divider:after {
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}


/* Very simple grid for example */
.containers { position: relative; width: 90%; margin: 20px auto; padding: 0; }

.containers .column, .containers .columns { float: left; display: inline; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; }

.containers .one-third.column { width: 10%; }

.containers .two-thirds.column { width: 25%; }
.containers .one-third.column:not(:first-child)::before{
    background: #ddd;
    bottom: 0;
    content: " ";
    margin-left: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
}
.containers .two-thirds.column ::before{
    background: #ddd;
    bottom: 0;
    content: " ";
    margin-left: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
}
```